# statement.executeUpdate() always returns 1

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I have a problem with the JDBC executeUpdate() method. It always returns 1 whether it updates a row or not. As far as I understand the method it should return 0 is no rows are altered.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
try {
conn = pool.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("{CALL UPDATE_USER (?,?,?)}");
        ps.setString(1, field.toString());
        ps.setString(2, change);
        ps.setString(3, userID);
        int updated = ps.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println(updated);
        if(updated==0){
            throw new NoUserException();
        }
        ps.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        log.error("An error occurred while creating the connection");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        pool.returnConnection(conn);
    }
```

Could this be because I'm using a prepared statement or a stored procedure?

Here is the stored procedure:

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE UPDATE_USER
(
  updateColumn IN user_tab_columns.column_name%type,
  changeStr IN VARCHAR2,
  unID IN VARCHAR2
)
IS
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
    'UPDATE
      users
SET ' || updateColumn || '= :1
WHERE
  uniqueID = :2'
  USING changeStr, unID; 
END;
```

Comment: It is probably updating to row with the same information, so you get 1 but see no change

Comment: What is the code in the UPDATE_USER procedure? And what are the values of the three parameters that you are passing in?

Comment: does update_user return a value?

Comment: @KevinBrydon passes in a column name(string), a string to change it to and a userID(string)

Comment: Usually if you do `UPDATE ... SET x = y WHERE id = ...`, then the row is updated, even if nothing was changed (`x` already was `y`). So the number of updated rows is 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can't get info from stored proc execution. If you want to get row count (or anything else) switch PROCEDURE to FUNCTION, add return clause in this function, and change your call to something like ? = CALL ... Test with sql%rowcount inside function to get impacted row count.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Callable statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.htmlto%20execute) a procedure or function.  And return the no of rows affected as a return parameter

Comment: I was trying to avoid using Callable statements to avoid using vendor specific implementations